# Condition inside select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
select id,status
from request
```

The status column of the above query returns some integer values. I need to put a condition to return some strings values instead of the integer values.

eg: if the status 1 then it should return "New" or if the status is 2 then it should return "Approved".

Comment: Another approach for consideration, to keep from having to put your label logic in every condition, would be to create a reference table that could join to to get the String Values, and then create a Foreign Key from the request table.  This way, if you needed to add a status or change the display label, you could do it in one place rather than have to find/change every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I despise mysterious integer values stored in a table with no clue as to their meaning.

My solution will take a bit more work up front, but it is well worth it in the long run.

Start by creating a new table of StatusValues:

```
StatusValues
------------
Status INT PRIMARY KEY
StatusValue VARCHAR(20)
```

Populate that table:

```
Status    StatusValue
------    -----------
1         New
2         Approved
```

Create a foreign key relationship from the Request table to this one:

```
ALTER TABLE request
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Request_StatusValues FOREIGN KEY (status)
    REFERENCES StatusValues (status);
```

And finally, write the query:

```
SELECT r.id, sv.StatusValue
    FROM request r
        INNER JOIN StatusValues sv
            ON r.status = sv.status;
```

The previously mysterious `request.status` column is now well documented and managed within the database.

Answer (score 4):

Use a case statement:

```
select 
    id, 
    case status
        when 1 then 'New' 
        when 2 then 'Approved' 
    end as status 
from 
    request
```

Although I would suggest you have a lookup table containing the numbers and a corresponding text string for the status value.

```
select 
    req.id, 
    stat.value as status
from 
    request as req inner join status as stat 
        on req.status = stat.id
```

Comment: +1 for the lookup table suggestion...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for that

```
select id,
       case status
          when 1 then 'New'
          when 2 then 'Approved'
       end as statusText
from request
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, case when status = 1 then 'NEW' when status = 2 then 'Approved' else 'Undefined' end as status
from request
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact syntax for SQL Server...

But here is the syntax that you could use for mySQL (a variant should work for you):

Note: This assumes that there are only two choices - if there are more, go with the case keyword.

```
select id, if(status = 1, "New", "Approved) from request
```

Comment: That doesn't work on the SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2 versions.... no similar construct available. SQL Server 2012 now has `IIF(...)` to do this